# how to add tables in room database without migrate

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I have an android app with room database this app contains a button and when the button pressed a dialog appear to type a word in it I need to create a new table its name is the word written in the dialog and i need this to happen each time the user opens the dialog and write on it so I can't change the version of the app and add migration each time a table is added how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Room is unsuitable for your use case. Room does not directly support creating new tables, etc. on the fly.

Either:

- Change your architecture to not create new tables, or
- Use Room for those tables that are known at compile time, and use a different database for the dynamic tables, or
- Do not use Room

Comment: can I do this with sqLite?

Comment: @M.Khaled: If you work with `SQLiteDatabase` directly, yes, though it may be complicated to maintain.